# Object is possibly 'undefined'. in array filter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I´m getting Object is possibly 'undefined' trying to use filter.

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    phone?: string;
}

let a: Person[] = [{name: "ASHLEE", age: 29},{name: "Brad", age: 32}]

const b = a.filter((item) =>
        item.phone.toLowerCase());

console.log(b);
```

How to solve this problem? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: as the phone is not in your array, you should be using like `(item.phone || '').toLowerCase()`

Comment: Phone is optional, so it may be undefined in runtime. For example, both persons in your array dont have phone. You probably want optional chaining, but the filter is a bit cryptic - if a string is truthy in lowercase, it is also truthy in uppercase.

Comment: @AdarshMohan thanks. It solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. To filter the `Persons` array you can do the following, no need to lower case it.

```js
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    phone?: string;
}

let a: Person[] = [{name: "ASHLEE", age: 29},{name: "Brad", age: 32}]

const b = a.filter((item) =>
        item.phone);

console.log(b);
```

If you are trying to lowercase `phone` you can apply a map function on the result.

```
const b = a.filter((item) =>
        item.phone).map(item => ({...item, phone: item.phone?.toLocaleLowerCase()}))
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0ViWQAHABY4IAfhp0GIFgQC+BAgBsIYZHBroo2EAG0AusgC8yQ3jKUaAIgCCAZQASAGQCiHuwBptnGgAmAE4lH2sKLjsAISg4ABNffy4AZkCw-BsogBUsciSOVMC-cUkaAHIAagBGQJTa+rrypWNVBBw6ZD5zbQA6GGA1SCgAChHgSHIASnMAPjZhYgmIcl7SkAgp3vI4EXHJueQRvF7T5fISiQ2ac7Wr6V6wLDcsBDgNF4B3aABhOAwICMpkoplM2h0sBpemosIwRnwpqwgA)